# meta query always fails even if data is correct

Tags: custom-post-types, query, post-meta, meta-query

I've following query -

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'accessory',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'accessory-bike',
            'value' => array("33"),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

And now I've this record in database -

[image]

520 is the ID of post having accessory post type. It still returns 0 results. I can't figure where the hell did I do wrong ? Stupid wordpress.

This generates following query -

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* 
        FROM wp_posts  
        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
        ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
        WHERE 1=1  
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'accessory' 
        AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
        AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'accessory-bike' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) IN ('33') ) )
        GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

which if you see carefully is completely accurate.

Comment: for your query to succeed, the value must be `33`, and as you can see in your screenshot, the value is a serialized array, not `33`.

Comment: @Milo I'm using that ACF plugin and it stores meta values like that. There's no way I can now search by these meta values. :(

Comment: Storing data that needs to be searchable in a serialized array is a bad idea, but given the choice of helper plugins you are using you are stuck with it. Perhaps: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115837/21376

Comment: So re http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115837/21376 if you do `'compare' => 'LIKE'` and `'value' => '"33"'` it should work...

Comment: You'll need to unserialize the meta value, much like they do here:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18463/how-to-extract-data-from-a-post-meta-serialized-array

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yea. I've decided to drop ACF plugin and manage post meta. I can then have multiple meta values for a single meta key without using serialization way.